# Workaround to do fast lookup using collection variable in a visual flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to use a flow to update the End Date on all `pse__Schedule__c` records associated to a project.

To do this I am querying(fast lookup) the `pse__Assignment__c` records that are associated to the project.

Then looping through the Assignment collection to collect the `pse__Schedule__c` record ids(using the lookup field on the Assignment record) into a collection variable.

My intention was to do a fast lookup using the collection variable containing the schedule record ids. Loop the Schedule sObject collection, assign the end date and update using fast update.

I figured I cannot use a fast lookup on a collection variable.

Has anyone found a workaround in visual flow to achieve this?

or

Is Apex invocable method the only viable solution to this?